# Refactoring to make an Angular component better

Tags: angular, typescript, refactoring

I have the following Angular component written in Typescript:

```
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {

@Input()
invoice: Document;

@Input()
declaration: Document;

private invoiceName: string;
private declarationName: string;

constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getInvoiceName(this.invoice);
    this.getDeclarationName(this.declaration);
}

getDeclarationName(declaration: Document) {
    this.dataService.getDocumentName(declaration.id)
        .subscribe((name) => this.declarationName = name);
}

getInvoiceName(invoice: Document) {
    this.dataService.getDocumentName(invoice.id)
        .subscribe((name) => this.invoiceName = name);
}
```

I have two items of the same type but I get them as inputs from different components and then I use them in my html template separately.
What I have right now is fine and works, but I find it too repetitive and it smells to me.

Do you have any idea how I can refactor it, so that I get just one method like `getDocumentName` for example and I can call it once inside the `onInit` but get the names of my `invoice` and my `declaration` separately?

Comment: The question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDocumentNames();
}

getDocumentNames() {
    this.dataService.getDocumentName(this.declaration.id)
        .subscribe((name) => this.declarationName = name);
    this.dataService.getDocumentName(this.invoice.id)
        .subscribe((name) => this.invoiceName = name);
}
```

Then on the dataservice level you can do a share to optimize the http calls.

Or since you want to retrieve multiple names at the same time you can consider changing the dataService to support a method that receives an array of Ids and make only one call on the component